# Flash builder for Ipad, reading images from local filesystem

Tags: flash, ios, ipad, builder

I'm currently developing an application for Ipad in which I download some images from my server and then i have to display them in to a spark image controller (i have a mobile project)
The images are wrote in the File.documentDirectory without problemi, but when i make attempts to refer them into a spark image control nothing is loaded. 
I attached an event listener on the image control for the ioerror event, and when fired it says that the url is not found.
I checked the url is correct because i tested it on the fileystem.

At the beginning of the project I was using the File.applicationDirectory and the images where correctly loaded ( to refer them i was using source="assets/mypicturedir/pict.jpg") and when locally tested I could even write in that folder.
Unfortunately when I deployed this method on the iPad it turned out that I cannot write in that folder. So I started using the File.documentsDirectory and I could write the images, but now i can't refer them from the image container.

Have you ever encountered this error?
Any ideas on how resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also write to: File.applicationStorageDirectory

You could embed the asset:

```
[Embed(source="assets/file.png")]
private var _class:Class;
```

Also, I'm unsure if you want a Spark Image component for iOS.  Flex Mobile projects are currently not supported by iOS, I believe.